# Multi-processing... Running 2 scripts on 2 terminals

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 2 scripts that start multiple processes. Right now I'm opening up two different terminals and running python start.py to start both the scripts. How can I achieve this with one command, or one running one script.

Start.py 1

```
# globals
my_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(foo):
    print("starting %s" % foo)
    try:
        addnews.varfoo)
    except Exception,e: 
        print str(e)

MAX_PROCESSES = 50
my_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

x = Var.objects.order_by('name').values('link')
for t in x:
    t = t.values()[0]
    my_pool.apply_async(my_function, args=(t,))
my_pool.close()
my_pool.join()
```

Start1.py 2

```
# globals
MAX_PROCESSES = 50
my_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(var):
   var.run_main(var)
   stop_event.set()


def var_scanner():
    # Since `t` could have unlimited size we'll put all `t` value in queue 
    while not stop_event.is_set(): # forever scan `values` for new items
    y = Var.objects.order_by('foo).values('foo__foo')
    for t in y:
        t = t.values()[0]
        my_queue.put(t)

try:
    var_scanner_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=var_scanner)
    var_scanner_process.start()
    my_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

    #while not stop_event.is_set():
    try: #  if queue isn't empty, get value from queue and create new process
        var = my_queue.get_nowait() # getting value from queue
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function, args=(var,))
        p.start()
    except Queue.Empty:
        print "No more items in queue"
        time.sleep(1) 
        #stop_event.set()

except KeyboardInterrupt as stop_test_exception:
     print(" CTRL+C pressed. Stopping test....")
     stop_event.set()
```

Comment: Note the syntax highlighting, you have an unclosed quote in script 2.

Comment: Why do both scripts have the same name `Start.py`?

Comment: You can use `xterm -e 'python start.py` to open a new window that runs the script. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What I want is to run both scripts at the same time. Because the function in start.py runs forever, I need to manually start start1.py. I want to have both of these infinite functions (var.runmain(), and addnews.var()) running at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can run the first script in the background on the same terminal, using the `&` shell modifier.

```
python start.py &
python start1.py
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had these both starting with another parent multiprocessing script but it wasn't working.